Landsat 7 NDVI errors?
I calculated NDVI using a method from a previous question I asked. I forgot that Landsat 7 has errors following 2003. I don't mind running it again but is there ways to correct for this error?
# Start of NDVI Calculation
def calculate_ndvi_from_multiband_tiff(multiband_tiff_path, output_folder, red_band_index, nir_band_index):
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Open the multi-band GeoTIFF
    with rasterio.open(multiband_tiff_path) as src:
        print(src.profile)

        # Read the red and NIR bands
        red = (src.read(red_band_index)).astype('float32')
        nir = (src.read(nir_band_index)).astype('float32')

        # Avoid division by zero and handle zero division warning
        np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

        ### rescale only data within range (1-65455) - 
        ### See https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-4-5-tm-collection-2-level-2-data-format-control-book
        red[(red > 0)&(red < 65456)] =  (red[(red > 0)&(red < 65456)] * 2.75e-5) + -0.2
        nir[(nir > 0)&(nir < 65456)] =  (nir[(nir > 0)&(nir < 65456)] * 2.75e-5) + -0.2

        # set negative reflectance values to 0 and saturated pixels to 1      
        red = np.clip(red, 0, 1)
        nir = np.clip(nir, 0, 1)

        # Calculate NDVI
        ndvi = (nir - red) / (nir + red)


        # # Create a custom colormap
        # cdict = {
        #     'red':   [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        #               (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        #               (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
        #               (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
        #     'green': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        #               (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        #               (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
        #               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
        #     'blue':  [(0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        #               (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        #               (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
        #               (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
        # }

        # custom_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('BlueYellowGreen', cdict)

        # # Plot NDVI data with the custom colormap and a colorbar
        # plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
        # plt.imshow(ndvi, cmap=custom_cmap, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
        # plt.colorbar(label='NDVI')
        # plt.title('NDVI')
        # plt.show()

        # Save the NDVI image
        profile = src.profile
        profile.update(dtype=rasterio.float32, count=1)

        # Construct the output path for NDVI image
        base_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(multiband_tiff_path))[0]
        ndvi_output_filename = f'{base_filename}_NDVI.tif'
        ndvi_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, ndvi_output_filename)
        
        with rasterio.open(ndvi_output_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(ndvi, 1)

    print(f'NDVI calculation complete. Output saved to {ndvi_output_path}')


# get all .tif (or .tiff) files in data folder
files = glob.glob('D:\PPR Downloads (Test)\Landsat_7_2015_05_09\*.tif') + glob.glob('D:\PPR Downloads (Test)\Landsat_7_2015_05_09\*.tiff')

# loop through and store all NDVI files in output folder
for file in files:
    calculate_ndvi_from_multiband_tiff(file, "D:\Landsat_NDVI\Landsat_7_2015_NDVI", 4, 5)

Also is this due to the failure , just want to make sure

Please add more details about the methods you applied. Each question is independent and should contain the required info in order to be answered.

@IliasMachairas Good point! I didn't think to add it because I didn't think it is too important to the question, but Ill include it. I am more so asking A) is this artifact in my Landsat 7 NDVI due to the failure and B) is there a way to sort of correct it as best I can (before calculating NDVI or after calculating NDVI.
